# Why `align-items:center` in flex can't vertically center the inner elements as a whole?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}    
#main{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:300px;
    height:180px;
    border:1px solid red;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
}       
#inner{
    width:100px;
    height:40px; 
    line-height:40px;
    border:1px solid red;
    text-align:center;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div id="inner">inner box</div>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOK9C.png" alt="">
</div>
```

I want to vertically center the inner div and image in the main div as a whole.
`flex-direction:column;`  make column as my flex direction,`justify-content:cneter;` horizontally center all inner elements in main div.
Why `align-items:center` in flex can't vertically center the inner elements as a whole?

Comment: `justify-content:cneter;` should be `justify-content:center;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in `justify-content:cneter;`.
change `cneter` to: `center`.